# Why is it that when I pass certain directory names to `ls`, sometimes it does not list their contents?

Tags: macos, shell, unix

[An example with trying to run `ls bin` and `ls etc` from `/`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYkx9.png)

I'm running macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. I use OhMyZSH as well as tmux. I don't understand why when I run `ls bin` and `ls etc` from /, the contents of the `bin` directory are printed but the contents of the `etc` directory are not. My `ls` is aliased to `ls -G` but I don't think this should matter.

I simply was expecting both directory contents to be listed. All I have tried is a simple `ls` of both directories from `/`.

Comment: Off topic here. One for https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Clifford thank you. I will post my question there after the 40 minute spam timer resets ‍

Comment: And please include the output *as text*, `formatted as code`, in the body of your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson okay will do. might i ask why the way i did it is not ideal?

Comment: @AlexanderWilliams, that's covered in detail at [Why not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: You have this behaviour because /etc is a symbolic to /private/etc.

Comment: @Philippe I thought this is as well but why is it that when I run `file etc` it just says it's a directory and doesn't allude to it being a link of any kind?

Comment: You can find out with `stat /etc`